# problem with session created by Node Js(Express session)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, express-session

I am creating a login system using React JS, Node JS(Express, Express-session, cookieParser, bodyParser, express-vaidator, pg, bcrypt and cors ) and PostgresSQL! I am try creating session to save data from de users and control the acess permission but a session shouldn't view in browser

This is the code from my route:

```js
app.post('/login',[
    body("emailInput").isEmail().normalizeEmail().withMessage('Este não é um email válido'),
    body("senhaInput").isLength({min: 8, max: 16}).trim().withMessage('Sua senha precisa ter entre 8 e 16 caracteres')
], (req, res) => { 
    const senha = req.body.senhaInput;
    const email = req.body.emailInput;
   
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if(!errors.isEmpty()){
        return res.json({errors: errors.array()} )
    }
    loginUser(email, senha, (result, rows) => {
        console.log(rows);
        req.session.user = rows;
        console.log("session", req.session.user);
        res.send(rows)
    })
})
```

This is the code from login user function:

```js
function loginUser(email, senha, callback) { //Função responsável de verificar se o usuário pode executar o login
    pool.connect((error, client, release) => {
        if (error) { //Se houver erro na conexão retorna o erro completo
            return console.error('Erro na conexão: ', error)
        } else {
        }
        client.query(`SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE email = '${email}';`, (error, result) => {
            release() 
            if (error) { //Se houver erro na execução da query retorna o erro completo
                console.error('Erro na execução da query: ', error.stack)
            } else {
                if(result.rows.length > 0){
                    bcrypt.compare(senha, result.rows[0].senha, (error, responseCompare) => {                        
                        if(responseCompare){
                            callback(responseCompare, result.rows)
                        } else {
                            callback(responseCompare)
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
        })
    })
}
```

This is the presets from express:

```js
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors({
    origin: ['http://localhost:3000'],
    methods: ['GET', 'POST'],
    credentials: true
}));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true })); 

app.use(session({
        key: "userId",
        secret: "subscribe",
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: false,
        cookie: {
            expires: 60 * 60 * 24,
        },
    })
);
```

The database comunication stay working and the validation too.

This is the function to submit my login form:

```js
function handleFormSubmit(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(campos)
    axios.post('http://localhost:3030/login', campos).then(response => {
      if (response.data.errors) {
        console.table(response.data.errors)
        response.data.errors.map(errorAtual => {
          if(errorAtual.param === 'senhaInput'){
            setSenhaError(errorAtual.msg)
          } else {
            setEmailError(errorAtual.msg)
          }
        })
      } else {
        setEmailError('')
        setSenhaError('')
        console.log(response.data)
      }
    })
  }
```

This code to recive the response from GET in "/login

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("http://localhost:3030/login").then((response) => {
      console.log(response.data)
    });
  }, []);
```

Here is the problem! This function always return { loggedIn: false }!

```js
app.get("/login", (req, res) => {
    if (req.session.user) {
      res.send({ loggedIn: true, user: req.session.user });
    } else {
      res.send({ loggedIn: false });
    }
});
```

Comment: I testing de Node APi on the Insomnia e and recive a cookie as response, can be problem from de browser?

Answer (score 0):

You are specifying `cookie: {expires: 60 * 60 * 24,},` as an express-session option.  That is incorrect.  The doc for express-session says: *"The expires option should not be set directly; instead only use the maxAge option."*  If you did use expires (in spite of what the doc says), it would need to be a Date object that represents the date/time of expiration, not an amount of time from now.

And, when you use to use the `maxAge` option, it has to be specified in milliseconds.  This is probably what you should be using.

```
cookie: {maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24},    // expire session in 24 hours
```